# Android Studio Theme editor and Blue print mode

Tags: android, plugins, android-studio, android-theme

I found this tweets from [Dmytro Danylyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1056263/dmytro-danylyk):
***tweet 1***:

> Blueprint mode - helps analyzing view hierarchy #AndroidDev #AndroidStudio

Screenshot:
[image]

link: https://twitter.com/dmytrodanylyk/status/604206979263897600

***tweet 2***:

> Theme Editor - should save a lot of time #AndroidDev #AndroidStudio

Screenshot:
[image]

link: https://twitter.com/dmytrodanylyk/status/604206270711730176

What is it?
Is it plugins or embedded features of Android Studio?
How can I enable this plugins / feautures?

**UPDATE:**
Response from [Dmytro Danylyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1056263/dmytro-danylyk): 
 https://twitter.com/dmytrodanylyk/status/624543583266316288

> it's new Android Studio feature which is not released yet.

I'll close the question.

Comment: I did't wait answer from Dmytro Danylyk. It's answer related to new feature of android studio, which not released yet. And now, this question has no sense

Comment: any idea when will it be released ?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Theme Editor is now available with the 1.4 Relase as this post explains how to use it:

[Android Studio Theme Editor](http://verybadtutorials.blogspot.mx/2015/10/using-theme-editor-in-android-studio.html)